# android studio lags when displaying suggestions and uses full CPU when trying to get the suggestions box

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am having a problem with android studio, suggestions, and class detection. I am Developing using Flutter and Whenever I try to write something it is not detected right away and it takes like 2 to 3 seconds for the widget class to be detected ad thus I can use the suggestion box to type the correct attributes.

during these lag seconds, my CPU usage goes to full (4 Threads maxed out) so it feels like the IDE is computing the suggestion box when I hit the keyboard shortcut. this behavior is somewhat new, as it wasn't laggy as this before.

In order to fix this, I tried invalidating caches and restarting multiple times and it didn't work.

I am on macOS Catalina 15.5.
Android Studio 4.0
Flutter master channel :

`Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-2.0.pre.95, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F96 darwin-x64, locale en)`

Is there something I can do? like clear caches somewhere else? is this an issue with dart Analyzer only? I don't know if it is a problem with Android Studio or Flutter.